# Concurrency access in Entity Framework 7

Tags: entity-framework, uwp

Today my question is what is the best way to support concurrency access in Entity Framework 7. For informations, I use it with SQLite in an UWP application.

I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx
But it seems "Reload" method missing. The namespace is System.Data.Entity which is missing in UWP and I don't find it in EntityFrameworkCore package.

Thanks for help.

Samuel

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: The latest install details for EF on UWP are here - are you using the latest version : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked to is for EF6.x. Here is a draft version of the docs for resolving concurrency conflicts in EF Core (formerly called EF7) https://docs.efproject.net/en/staging/saving/concurrency.html.

Comment: Hi Rowan,
Thanks for your help. This will help me to solve my issue.